# CyanogenMod 9 gives AuthenticatorException while adding account

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod

I had installed custom ROM CyanogenMod 9. But I am not able to make Google play work in it. It doesn't show Add Google Account option in the *Accounts & Sync* option in *Settings*.

I had also googled and found that I need the latest gapps to be installed. So, I downloaded the *latest gapps* from [goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps) but still I am not able to setup my Google Account. When I installed google play apk and run it, it gets closed after few seconds. I checked the logs and it gave be below exception,

```
D/AccountManagerService( 276): there is no authenticator for com.google, bailing out
D/AccountManagerService( 276): bind attempt failed for Session: expectLaunch false, connected false, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 0.0, addAccount, accountType com.google, requiredFeatures null
I/AccountManagerService( 276): unbind() over.
D/Finsky ( 4061): [1] 13.run: AuthenticatorException while adding account: android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure. Finishing.
```

So, anybody had the same issue if future please let me know. What can be the way that I can solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the gapps from here: http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip (latest)  download the zip.
2. check the MD5 and flash it from recovery.
3. Wipe data and cache.
4. reboot.

Comment: how to check the MD5? also I am having ICS now so for that also I need to flash gapps of Jelly Bean?

Comment: ooooops sorry wrong link !

Comment: download it frm here: http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip. Try to flash gapps immediately after flashing the rom without reboot in between.
wipe data n cache and reboot.

Comment: already did that! didn't work.

Comment: then ur mod might not be stable version of CM9.Try to download the stable mod for ur device, don't go for experimental/nightly versions...